# winforms progress bar not updating properly according to Google Cloud IUploadProgress c#

Tags: c#, winforms, google-cloud-storage

So I'm uploading objects to Google Cloud Storage with `UploadObjectAsync`. I update a progress bar using `IUploadProgress.Status` but the progress bar doesn't seem to be syncing correctly with the Uploading Status. Basically when the upload is complete I change a label's text saying "Upload completed". That happens when the upload is complete but sometimes the progress bar is still empty (and fills up afterwards). I can't figure out if the `Completed` status happens to fast for the progress bar to update.

```
public async void UploadAsync(string projectID, string bucketName, GoogleCredential credentials, string filePath,string _objectName, StringBuilder _objectData, List<string> _metaData, string objectName = null)
{
    // Instantiates a client.
    using (var storageClient = Google.Cloud.Storage.V1.StorageClient.Create(credentials))
    {
        try
        {
            string[] lines = _objectData.ToString().Split(new[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

            using (var memStream = new MemoryStream())
            using (var memStream2 = new MemoryStream())
            using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(memStream))
            using (var streamWriter2 = new StreamWriter(memStream2))
            using (var csvWriter = new CsvWriter(streamWriter, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) )
            {
                //for data.csv
                foreach (var line in lines)
                {
                    string[] lineItems = line.Split(',');
                    foreach (var singleItem in lineItems) {
                        csvWriter.WriteField(singleItem);
                    }
                    csvWriter.NextRecord();
                    
                }
                streamWriter.Flush(); //always flush streamWriter after writing
                memStream.Position = 0;

                foreach (var entry in _metaData)
                {
                    streamWriter2.WriteLine(entry);
                }

                
                streamWriter2.Flush();
                memStream2.Position = 0;
                using (FileStream fileMeta = new FileStream(_objectName + "meta.txt", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
                {
                    
                    memStream2.CopyTo(fileMeta);
                }

                setMax((int)(memStream.Length + memStream2.Length)); //sets progress bar max to be length of both memory streams

                // set minimum chunksize just to see progress updating
                var uploadObjectOptions = new Google.Cloud.Storage.V1.UploadObjectOptions
                {
                    ChunkSize = Google.Cloud.Storage.V1.UploadObjectOptions.MinimumChunkSize
                };

                // Hook up the progress callback
                var progressReporter = new Progress<Google.Apis.Upload.IUploadProgress>(OnUploadProgress);
                
                Console.WriteLine(bucketName);
                Console.WriteLine("objectName" + objectName);

                bucketName = "csv-upload-bucket";
                /*storageClient.UploadObject*/
                await storageClient.UploadObjectAsync(
                    bucketName,
                    _objectName + ".csv",
                    "application/csv",
                    memStream,
                    uploadObjectOptions,
                    progress: progressReporter).ConfigureAwait(true);

                await storageClient.UploadObjectAsync(
                    bucketName,
                    _objectName + "meta.txt",
                    "application/text",
                    memStream2,
                    uploadObjectOptions,
                    progress: progressReporter).ConfigureAwait(true);
            }
        }
        catch (Google.GoogleApiException e)
            when (e.Error.Code == 409)
        {
            // When creating the bucket - The bucket already exists.  That's fine.
            Console.WriteLine(e.Error.Message);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // other exception
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

```
void OnUploadProgress(Google.Apis.Upload.IUploadProgress progress)
{
    switch (progress.Status)
    {
        case Google.Apis.Upload.UploadStatus.Starting:
            setMin(0); //sets progress bar value to 0
            UpdateProgressBar(0);
            break;

        case Google.Apis.Upload.UploadStatus.Completed:
            UpdateProgressBar(getMax()); //sets progress bar value to max
            setResultLabelText("Upload completed");
            setLoadCompleteBttnEnabled(true); //enables OK bttn
            setCancelLoadBttnEnabled(false);
            break;

        case Google.Apis.Upload.UploadStatus.Uploading:
            UpdateProgressBar((int)progress.BytesSent);
            setLoadCompleteBttnEnabled(false);
            setCancelLoadBttnEnabled(true);
            Console.WriteLine("busy uploading"); //this never seems to be called

            break;
        case Google.Apis.Upload.UploadStatus.Failed:
            setResultLabelText("Upload failed");
            Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine + progress.Exception);
            break;

    }
}
```

Comment: Why the Backgroundworker? You are already using Async?

Comment: Good point. I thought I'd need it to process in the background so it doesn't freeze the UI on upload but I don't actually need it since I'm already doing an async operation. It doesn't change anything even after taking it out though.